# What does "srmount error" mean?

Tags: c, linux

In the list of errno for linux, there is an error 69 like this:

```
no 68 == Advertise error;
no 69 == Srmount error;
no 70 == Communication error on send;
```

Does anybody know the reason of this error? Any potential reason is appreciated.

Comment: I only have version 2.6.32 of the kernel at work, but searching through it the `ESRMNT` name is only used in `errno` header files and no source files. Note that the value is different depending on platform. It's not defined in POSIX either, leading me to think it's an old Linux-specific error that's no longer used.

Comment: I guess it is inherited from the posix interface and is there mostly for compliance with the standard.

Comment: C'mon people, if you know what it is then answer, but please don't just paste the first reference you found while googling - the OP can google by himself.

Answer (score 3):

> This error is RFS specific. It occurs when an attempt is made to stop RFS while resources are still mounted by remote machines, or when a resource is readvertised with a client list that does not include a remote machine with the resource currently mounted.

@ [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1075/msgs-2057/index.html)

Comment: If it's that, the OP might want to read about [RFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Sharing) as well. It's probably obsolete, which is why `ESRMNT` is never referenced anywhere in the Linux kernel source.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg is probably right. And BTW cutting and pasting some obscure reference from the first entry you found on google is not what I qualify as a good answer.

Comment: I'm here not to paste first references from google, I'm as interested in knowledge as author. I did my research and didn't find any other relevant explanation. Even in appropriate header file from kernel it just says "srmount error" in comments.